# openCL Kernel segmentation fault in pi calculation

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, opencl, pi

Good evening all,

I am trying to design an openCL kernel to calculate pi. This is a school assignment and we were told to use this equation:

Pi/4 = 1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9 - ...

Here is my kernel design that is currently generating a segfault and I am not sure why:

```
__kernel void calculatePi(int numIterations, __global float *outputPi, __local float* local_result, int numWorkers)
{
    // Get global ID for worker
    const uint gid = get_global_id(0);
    const uint lid = get_local_id(0);
    const uint offset = numIterations*gid*2;

    float sum = 0.0f;

    for (int i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++)
    {
        local_result[i] = 0.0f;
    }   

    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    for (int i=0; i<numIterations; i++) 
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            sum += 1 / (1 + 2*i + offset);
        else
            sum -= 1 / (1 + 2*i + offset);
    }

    local_result[gid] = sum;    

    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

    if (lid == 0)
    {        
        outputPi[0] = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++)
        {
            outputPi[0] += local_result[i]; 
        }
        outputPi[0] *= 4;
    }    
}
```

Basically, my thought process was to have 16 workers in parallel. each worker will take numIterations terms and determine a partial calculation of pi. In this case, I'm also using 16 for numIterations. The terms alternate, so for every odd term I subtract and every even I add. The first worker is responsible for calculating the first 16 terms, the next worker the next 16 terms, and so on to create 16 partial sums of 16 digits each. Once each worker has calculated their partial sum, I have the first worker take all of the partial sums and add it up to send out. I also multiply by 4 to complete the equation.

My issue is that I keep getting a segmentation fault within my main program at the following line:

```
ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, result_buffer, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(result), &result, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

Here are the other uses of "result" that could be causing this issue:

```
float result[1] = {0}; // Initialized at top of main
/* Create buffers to hold the text characters and count */
cl_mem result_buffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(result), result, NULL);
printf("Final calculated value: %f \n", result[0]);
```

Can anyone give me insight as to why I'm getting the segfault when trying to read the result buffer back into result?

The full code can be seen within my github: https://github.com/TreverWagenhals/TreverWagenhals/tree/master/School/Heterogeneous%20Computing/Lab2

Thanks.

EDIT: I've found the issue that was in my code. I was creating a variable called numWorkers and passing that into one of the kernel arguments, which apparently wasn't correct. In the process of simplifying my code I was able to remove it and use the global_size variable directly, which now resolves the seg fault issue and shows the data each call.

Now I'm having an issue within my Kernel where 4 is being returned instead of the value for pi. I will debug further and create a new question if I can't see the issue. I'll have

Comment: the posted snippets of code are not calling each other,   Do you expect use to guess as to how they are related?

Comment: I assume you call `clEnqueueReadBuffer()` after enqueueing the kernel. Let's rule out that the kernel as the source of the crash first: call `clFinish()` immediately after enqueueing the kernel and see where it crashes now. (I rather suspect your enqueue call or one of the arguments is problematic.)

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that the steps for most openCL programs are fairly repetitive. Here is a link to my github though that I currently have it uploaded to with the seg fault still exisiting: https://github.com/TreverWagenhals/TreverWagenhals/tree/master/School/Heterogeneous%20Computing/Lab2

Comment: I tried what you suggested and put clFinish after the enqueue. The queue returns CL_SUCCESS which should rule out my kernel. I'll upload the change to GIT when I'm back on my computer. Any suggestions with that note and the code shown now though? Thanks

Comment: You are getting 4 instead of PI ? Because you divide integer value by another integer value, so fractional part is rejected, you need to use floating point arithmetic when `sum += 1 / (1 + 2*i + offset);` (i and offset are ints) is performed. You can write numerator as 1.0 instead of 1. `Pi/4 = 1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9 - ...`,  `1/3` is 0, `1/5` is 0, so now you have `PI/4 = 1` so PI is 4.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for explaining that to me. I would have never thought of that without you pointing it out. I made changes and am now getting the result I was expecting. Thanks again!